# Slow Data Retrieval from Meetime API in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm facing an issue when retrieving data from the Meetime API in Power BI. I'm using the following code to paginate the data:

```
let
Paginacao = List.Generate(() =

        [Records = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.meetime.com.br/v2", [RelativePath = "/calls?start=" & Number.ToText(Start), Headers = [Authorization =#"TOKEN"]]))[data], Start = 0],
        each Value.Is([Records], type list) = true,
        each [Records = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.meetime.com.br/v2", [RelativePath = "/calls?start=" & Number.ToText(Start), Headers = [Authorization =#"TOKEN"]]))[data], Start = [Start] + 100]
    )

in
Paginacao
```

However, data retrieval is taking hours to return all data from the Meetime API. I'm respecting the API rate limit, but I'm still experiencing this delay. What can I do to optimize this process and obtain the data more efficiently?